# Getting AccessTokenFailed using ServiceStack FacebookAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

trying to use facebook's oauth with servicestack, i'm hitting url
localhost:60782/api/auth/facebook

being taken to facebook's auth dialog but after clicking allow, i'm being redirected back to my redirect URL with #f=AccessTokenFailed
localhost:60782/api/users#f=AccessTokenFailed

anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem when setting the facebook authentication up.  I found it difficult to pinpoint the problem because servicestack catches the web exception and effectively discards it.  To work out what was happening I downloaded and compiled the service stack code.  I was then able to change my project to reference my local service interace DLL which enabled me to set a debug point in the facebook auth provider.

In my case I was getting a proxy authentication error, caused by the server attempting to contact facebook without any credentials.  I overcame this by reconfiguring my dev pc and production pc so that they didnt go via the proxy.

Comment: indeed that's what i ended up doing. after fighting with some dll hell, i figured out my problem. copying my fb secret from a browser to web.config somehow inserted a tab character prefix. so in the end it was user error :P i'll give u the accepted answer cause that is the solution to fix this kind of thing